# ¿Cómo unir 2 imágenes diferentes en una sola?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Tengo 2 imágenes y necesito unirlas en una sola.

Exactamente necesito que las 2 imágenes se solapen entre ellas y creen una nueva.

Ambas imágenes se han de ver al 50%, como si cogieras 2 imágenes en Photoshop y las unieras.

El resultado será una nueva imagen.

¿Alguien sabe como poder hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de como debería de quedar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a poner por ejemplo que queremos unir estas dos imágenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ell, debemos crear una nueva imagen a partir de las dos anteriores de esta forma:

```
UIImage *image0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image0.jpeg"];
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpeg"];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image0.size);
[image0 drawAtPoint:CGPointZero blendMode:kCGBlendModeOverlay alpha:1.0];
[image1 drawAtPoint:CGPointZero blendMode:kCGBlendModeOverlay alpha:1.0];
UIImage *blendedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Consiguiendo el resultado siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perfecto es lo que buscaba gracias